# Opening multiple documents with Process.Start()

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a program that will open multiple documents with a single click and specify size and location for each individual document window. I was having decent success with a rudimentary program to test the opening and positioning operations until I tried to open a second Word or Excel document.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process resize = new Process();

            resize.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Pete\\Desktop\\TEST1.txt";
            resize.Start();
            resize.WaitForInputIdle();
            MoveWindow(resize.MainWindowHandle, 10, 10, 500, 500, true);

            resize.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Pete\\Desktop\\MSWTEST1.docx";
            resize.Start();
            resize.WaitForInputIdle();
            MoveWindow(resize.MainWindowHandle, 20, 20, 500, 500, true);

            resize.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Pete\\Desktop\\MSXTEST1.xlsx";
            resize.Start();
            resize.WaitForInputIdle();
            MoveWindow(resize.MainWindowHandle, 30, 30, 500, 500, true);

            resize.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Pete\\Desktop\\TEST2.txt";
            resize.Start();
            resize.WaitForInputIdle();
            MoveWindow(resize.MainWindowHandle, 40, 40, 500, 500, true);

            resize.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Pete\\Desktop\\MSWTEST2.docx";
            resize.Start();
            resize.WaitForInputIdle();
            MoveWindow(resize.MainWindowHandle, 50, 50, 500, 500, true);

            resize.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Pete\\Desktop\\MSXTEST2.xlsx";
            resize.Start();
            resize.WaitForInputIdle();
            MoveWindow(resize.MainWindowHandle, 60, 60, 500, 500, true);
         }
    }
}
```

The program tries to open two .txt files using Notepad, two .docx files using MSWord, and two .xlsx files using MSExcel. No matter what order I open the documents in the program throws an InvalidOperationException on the WaitForInputIdle line immediately after opening a second Word or Excel file. Any help fixing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the same issue arise if you don't reuse `resize`, i.e., have a different `Process` for each?

Comment: Why would you Start() multiple documents in the SAME process (resize)?

Comment: @Austin - Yes the same issue arises whether I use 1 process or 6 processes.

Comment: OR you could do it via static: `Process proc = Process.Start(Execut, args);`. This way you know you will always have a new window. Edit: Didn't test it with office files, only chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to open a Word or Excel document the application (depending on version) being executed simply looks for the same application already running, asks it to open a new "window" and shuts down.  This means the application you're actually running never really gets a message pump--which leads to `WaitForInputIdle` thowing an `InvalidOperationException` (as [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

I suggest you simply try to catch and ignore the exception--I'm not sure of any way to tell if Word/Excel successfully opened the document via `Process.Start`
Update: conceptually, If you *do* get the exception that means Word/Excel found another running instance and switched to it--so, presumably that's some degree of "success".

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Explained why it was happening and what to do about it. I can't upvote yet so I'll just give it +1.

Answer (score 3):

When you open the second Word or Excel document, the launching process detects that Word/Excel is already started and simply sends the other process the document information and shuts down.

A simpler application, such as notepad, does not have that behavior.

That means that, in that case, the `Process` instance that you have the second time you launch is worth precisely zilch in order to control the document which is being opened.

Comment: So this diagnoses the problem, but the answer would be improved greatly if you also included an appropriate solution for resolving the issue.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation of why it's happening as this information will certainly be useful going forward.

Comment: @Servy: You are right - but I do not know the constraints, and I do not see a solution that stays on the same level of generality. Will it be enought to handle just the case of MS Office? Should OpenOffice be considered? What if e.g. SublimeText, which has a similar "attach to running process" behavior, is used as the default text editor?

Comment: @Jean - Given your explanation and if I further clarified that my application only needs to deal with .txt, .docx and .xlsx files can you suggest a way to set the position of the second Word or Excel document window since I can't use MainWindowHandle because at that point in the code the process has closed?

Comment: @PeteHogrefe I will look into it later then.

Answer (score 0):

How about using multiple Process objects or trying MS Office INterrop assemblies like this

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CreatingandOpeningMicrosoftDocumentfrom.NETUsingCSharp11262005050939AM/CreatingandOpeningMicrosoftDocumentfrom.NETUsingCSharp.aspx